# Is there a simple proof for the behaviour of this solution?

Tags: inequality, quadratics, alternative-proof, symmetry

Let $0 <s \le 1$, and suppose that $0 <b \le a$ satisfy 
$$ ab=s,a+b=1+\sqrt{s}.$$

Then $a \ge 1$.

I have a proof for this claim (see below), but I wonder if there are easier or alternative proofs.

> In particular, my proof is based on explicit computation of $a,b$ in terms of $s$ (solving the quadratic). Can we avoid that?

*The proof:*

We have $a+\frac{s}{a}=1+\sqrt s$, or

$$ a^2-(1+\sqrt s)a+s=0,$$

which implies (since we assumed $a \ge b$) that
$$ a=\frac{1}{2}(1+\sqrt s+\sqrt{1+2\sqrt s-3s}).$$

Thus, $a \ge 1$ iff $$\sqrt s+\sqrt{1+2\sqrt s-3s} \ge 1 \iff \\
1+2\sqrt s-2s+2\sqrt s \sqrt{1+2\sqrt s-3s} \ge 1 \iff \\ \sqrt s-s+\sqrt s \sqrt{1+2\sqrt s-3s} \ge 0 \iff \\
1-\sqrt s+ \sqrt{1+2\sqrt s-3s} \ge 0 \iff \\ \sqrt{1+2\sqrt s-3s} \ge \sqrt s-1.$$

(We passed from the first line to the second line by squaring).

The last inequality clearly holds, since the LHS $\ge 0$, and the RHS is $\le 0$.
(since we assumed $s \le 1$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** $(a-1)(b-1) = ab - a - b + 1  = s - \sqrt{s} \leq 0 $.

Hence, conclude that $ a \geq 1 \geq b $, with equality when $ s = 1$.

Comment: Thank you, that's very elegant. It seems to me that one can easily generalize this, to find when the largest solution for a quadratic is greater than $1$. (i.e. find an easy condition in terms of the coefficients of the quadratic).

Comment: Viewing it as a monic quadratic $f(x) = (x-a)(x-b)$,  what we're doing is testing $f(1)$ to see if $f(1)  \leq 0 $. If so, we're guaranteed a root $ \geq 1$. That's the easy (and well known) condition that I'm using.

Comment: OK, great I understand now. (this is because we know $f$ must be positive for sufficiently large $x$, so if $f(1) <0$ it must cross the $x$-axis somewhere after $1$.) Thank you for this clarification. This is exactly the illuminating explanation I was looking for.